# How do I fill a dynamic 2D Array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic-arrays

Why does this:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
p = 1
For i = 1 To LRow
If Sheets("Data").Range("U" & 4 + i).Value > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To p, 1 To 2)
    Arr(p, 1) = Sheets("Data").Range("U" & 4 + i).Value
    Arr(p, 2) = Sheets("Data").Range("N" & 4 + i).Value
    p = p + 1
End If
Next
```

results in "run time error 9 - Subscript out of range" at the ReDim line?
I do not know the number of array rows prior to entering the for loop. The column number should always be 2. Doing the same thing but with an 1D Array works, though!
Any help?

Comment: If you know the final size of the array before the loop (`1 To LRow`), size the array once and enjoy a terrific performance boost, by avoiding a resize at every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ReDim Preserve` you can only resize the last dimension of an array.
See here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement
If you are looking for a solution, then you can swap array to be `Arr(2,p)` as you say column number will always be 2.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, you can only redim preserve the last dimension.

But you can also use other methods to find the number of "rows" needed and set that prior to rediming the array:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
p = 1
dim rws as long
rws = Application.WorkSheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Data").Range("U5:U" & Lrow+4),">0")
Redim Arr(1 to rws,1 to 2)
For i = 1 To LRow
If Sheets("Data").Range("U" & 4 + i).Value > 0 Then

    Arr(p, 1) = Sheets("Data").Range("U" & 4 + i).Value
    Arr(p, 2) = Sheets("Data").Range("N" & 4 + i).Value
    p = p + 1
End If
Next
```